# Powershell Script- Conversion from Batch File

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have this working as a batch file but when I tried converting to Powershell, my file doesn't transcode like it does in the batch file.  It's supposed to ask 2 input questions, the link to a video and the local ip address.  Once it has the answers to the 2 input questions, Vlc player is supposed to open the video link and then transcode the file in real time from .flv format to another format and start playing on vlc as it's transcoding.  Then at the same time, I start playing the the converted file on vidcast through the chrome browser on my local network and then the converted video can also be cast  to a television using chromecast.

I think the problem is on the bolded area of the powershell script but have no experience with this and don't know how to fix it.  Can someone help, Please.

Batch File

```
@echo off
set /p input="Insert your Http link: "
set /p input1="Insert your Local IP address: "
rem VLC
cd "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC"

start vlc.exe %input% :sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream} :sout-all :sout-keep

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe "https://dabble.me/cast/?video_link=http://%input1%/stream"
exit
```

Power Shell

```
$link = read-host "Enter an Http Link "
$ip = read-host "Enter your Local Ip Address "

& "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "$link" ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream}:sout-all :sout-keep" 

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://dabble.me/cast/?video_link=http://$ip/stream"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [`Start-Process`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) with an `ArgumentList` set?

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe' -ArgumentList "$link",":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream}:sout-all :sout-keep"
```

`Start-Process` takes a file path (`-FilePath`) as the process to start. It then takes a String array of arguments (`-ArgumentList`) to incorporate with the executable being started.

`FilePath` should be the full path to the executable (or relative path if you prefer)

`ArgumentList` should be all your individual arguments, comma separated

All in all it should look like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Where\VLC\Is\Located.exe" -ArgumentList "1stArg"[,"2ndArg"[,...]]
```

Comment: Total beginner here.  If I was supposed to copy that line of code as is, it didn't bring up the vlc player.  If I was supposed to alter that line, could you give a little more instruction.

Comment: @user3444610, Read the docs on Start-Process. I've updated my answer to help you along. It would be helpful if we knew what you were trying to access (the link)

Comment: The link is to a video in .flv format which is then being transcoded to a format that can be understood by the Chromecast.  The .flv format can't be understood by the Chromecast.  So the problem is with this line   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream}:sout-all :sout-keep"    I'm not sure which are arguments and which aren't and how to code it.  I'll see if I can research how to to do it.  Thanks

Comment: It's now working although I'm sure the code is probably not good.